# Stop apt-get from trying to download translations from specific repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, language, reprepro

I have a custom Debian repository deployed with no translation packages which I created using `reprepro` utility. Everytime `apt-get update` is run I see requests to *i18n* packages which I don't have and hence *404* is returned back to clients. This hasn't been a problem so far, but it seems like a misconfiguration issue that should be addressed.

I managed to stop `apt-get` from downloading all translations by putting these lines (thanks to a tip similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184665/how-apt-get-determines-when-to-download-translation-file) one)

```
Acquire::Languages {
 "none";
}
```

to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99languages`

I want to this to work only for my repo.
I've stumbled upon similar problems with setting up repository-specific proxies. These problems have been solved with adding a repository URI before "none" but this doesn't seem to do the job for Languages options.

I'll be very thankful to anyone who might recommend a proper solution.

I'm using a Debian Jessie-based distribution.

Comment: Are you using a custom Debian repository in Ubuntu?

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm using a modified Ubuntu, so lsb_release won't really shed any light on the problem. `lsb_release` modules are not included. Guys, correct me if I'm wrong. I guess this question could also be asked on *ServerFault*  or *Unix & Linux *but I reckoned AskUbuntu is more applicable here as it's a package management issue that is relevant to Ubuntu. And therefore more people will benefit from it.

Comment: @staroselskii in any case, I poked around the manpage, and the only mention of server-specific settings are for http/https/ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[lang=none]` to your repository's entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the file for it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.  For example, the repository:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```

becomes:

```
deb [lang=none] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```